# Bonita: Create your own form widget

Tags: business-process-management

Bonita Open Solution (http://www.bonitasoft.com/) has many widgets for creating forms, but user requirements demand more...

so, does anybody know how to create your own widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might take a look to this post which goes over the basics of custom widget design:

https://www.evoketechnologies.com/blog/custom-widgets-bonita-bpm-ui-designer/

Comment: the link is expired, if you have code, can u please post the code in your answer.